# grunt custom task copying files that should be omitted

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, file-copying, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a pair of `grunt copy` tasks defined:

```
copy : {
    develop : {
        expand : true,
        flatten : false,
        cwd : "develop/",
        src : ["index.html", "gwt/**/*", "!**/*.less", "!**/*.scss", "modules/**/*", "components/**/*", "resources/**/*", "!resources/styles/**"],
        dest : "build/"
    },
    // TODO: figure out how to update glyphicon paths to build
    bootstrap_assets : {
        expand : true,
        flatten : false,
        src : ["bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/**/*"],
        dest : "build/"
    },
}
```

and combine them in the custom task

```
// Intermediate Task - Copy dev resources to build
grunt.registerTask("copy_dev", ["copy:develop", "copy:bootstrap_assets"]);
```

Inside the `modules` folder, I want to copy all the contents BUT the `scss` files.  When I run `grunt copy:develop`, that has the behavior I expect, with all files except `*.scss` copying over.  However, when I run `grunt copy_dev`, all the contents of `modules` gets copied over.

This is part of the output from `grunt copy_dev --verbose`:

```
Running "copy:develop" (copy) task
Verifying property copy.develop exists in config...OK
Files: develop/modules/front-page -> build/modules/front-page
Files: develop/modules/front-page/front-page.html -> build/modules/front-page/front-page.html
Files: develop/modules/front-page/front-page.scss -> build/modules/front-  page/front-page.scss
Files: develop/modules/login -> build/modules/login
Files: develop/modules/login -> build/modules/login
Files: develop/modules/login/bigLogo.png -> build/modules/login/bigLogo.png
Files: develop/modules/login/login-view.html -> build/modules/login/login-view.html
Files: develop/modules/login/login.js -> build/modules/login/login.js
Files: develop/modules/login/login.scss -> build/modules/login/login.scss
Files: develop/modules/login/logo -> build/modules/login/logo
Files: develop/modules/login/logo/lg.png -> build/modules/login/logo/lg.png
Files: develop/modules/login/logo/md.png -> build/modules/login/logo/md.png
Files: develop/modules/login/logo/sm.png -> build/modules/login/logo/sm.png
```

As you can see, there are a number of `*.scss` files being copied when executing the custom task, whereas they do not via the regular `copy:$name` call.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that Grunt processes your src/dest directives from left to right to build the list of files to copy, rather than apply all rules at the same time (http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns), so:

- "index.html" > adds index.html
- "gwt/**/*" > adds everything under gwt
- "!**/*.less" > removes all less files **from the current copy list**, that is less files **under gwt**
- "!**/*.scss" > idem
- "modules/**/*" > adds everything under modules **including less and scss files**
- ...

So you need to change your order if you want to prevent all less and scss from being copied:

```
src : ["index.html", "gwt/**/*", "modules/**/*", "components/**/*", "resources/**/*", "!**/*.less", "!**/*.scss", "!resources/styles/**"]
```